# Add an intranet ip address to security zone programatically?

Tags: asp.net, dns-zone

I have an ASP.NET application and have published to our company's intranet.

Problem I have here is getting 350 computers to add the site's IP address (ie: 123.1.1.123) to the Local Intranet trusted sites zone, located in the browser's

```
Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> Local Intranet -> Sites -> Advanced
```

Is there anyway to do this automatically?

Say, perhaps a network login script?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, one way (hopefully not THE way) is to have the network admins modify the login scripts. Here is one example, borrowed from TechNet:

```
On Error Resume Next

Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

strComputer = "."
Set objReg=GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\" _
& "ZoneMap\Domains\microsoft.com"

objReg.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath

strValueName = "http"
dwValue = 2

objReg.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, strValueName, dwValue
```

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/02/14/how-can-i-add-a-web-site-to-the-trusted-sites-zone.aspx